# How to ignore in Sonar OpenJpa methods pcSet / pcGet?

Tags: java, sonarqube, openjpa

In my application we are using OpenJpa. By decompiling my classes, I can see some methods I haven´t typed, for instance `pcGetid`:

```
public long getId()
  {
    return pcGetid(this);
  }
  (...)
  private static final long pcGetid(...)
```

My original java file looks like:

```
public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
```

I assume that is some internal OpenJpa procedure. The problem comes when Sonar analyzes my code. Many `Unused private method` major violations appears, because some of those methods are not used. 
Is ther a way to ignore sonar in these cases? I can not use `//NOSONAR` because in my code those methods does not exist.

It might be usefull to know in which phase of the build process this methods are added, so I can analyze the content before it happens.

Any idea would be appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using SonarQube 4.0, you can use the issue exclusion mechanism to exclude all issues on this "Unused private method" for a set of java files :http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus#NarrowingtheFocus-patterns